# Nuxt3 & Github Action : Error: no such file or directory

Tags: github-actions, nuxtjs3

I'm using the following github action when pushing my Nuxt3 website:

```
name: Generate a build and push to another branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Push

    steps:
      - name: git-checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: pnpm-setup
        uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
        with:
          version: 6.0.2

      - name: Install all dependencies
        run: pnpm install

      - name: Build
        run: pnpm run build # The build command of your project

      - name: Push
        uses: s0/git-publish-subdir-action@develop
        env:
          REPO: self
          BRANCH: build # The branch name where you want to push the assets
          FOLDER: dist # The directory where your assets are generated
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # GitHub will automatically add this - you don't need to bother getting a token
          MESSAGE: "Build: ({sha}) {msg}" # The commit message
```

However, the `dist` folder doesn't seem to be created and I'm getting the following error in the logs:

```
Run s0/git-publish-subdir-action@develop
  env:
    PNPM_HOME: /home/runner/setup-pnpm/node_modules/.bin
    REPO: self
    BRANCH: build
    FOLDER: dist
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ***
    MESSAGE: Build: ({sha}) {msg}
Cloning into '/tmp/git-publish-subdir-action-9N77GC/repo'...

From https://github.com/me/mywebsite.com
 * [new branch]      build      -> build

##[info] Checking if branch build exists already
data   build

Switched to branch 'build'

##[info] Updating branch build
##[info] Removing all files from target branch
##[info] Copying all files from /home/runner/work/mywebsite.com/mywebsite.com/dist
Error: no such file or directory: /home/runner/work/mywebsite.com/mywebsite.com/dist/
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/s0/git-publish-subdir-action/develop/action/dist/index.js:115:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/runner/work/_actions/s0/git-publish-subdir-action/develop/action/dist/index.js:79:58)
```

Comment: Are there any errors on calling `pnpm run build`  step?

Answer (score 0):

With Nuxt3 the folder where assets are generated is `.output`, not `dist`.

```
FOLDER: .output # The directory where your assets are generated
```